# How to remove a duplicate title tag and meta description tag with canonical link

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have run SEO tool for my website, it showed that I have a duplicate title tag and meta description tag, both are in "domain.com/" and "/index.html" , they are the same file. How do I use Canonical Link to remove the duplicate tags ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

if it's showing up just in SEO software don't worry about it, Google's smart enough to know it's one page

Answer (score 2):

You're coming across a classic duplicate-content issue.

The quickest way to get around this is to edit your `index.html` page markup and include a [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) within the `<head>` of your page.

Try this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://your-domain.com/" />
```

What this does is tell the search engines that the two URLs (the domain root, and `/index.html`) are the same page and that it should only index the `domain.com/` version.

This won't stop people being able to still access the same page via `/index.html` and just `domain.com/`, but it should remove the index.html version from the search engine indexes fairly quickly.

One very important thing to bear in mind: you need to ensure that you don't drop this `link` into a common/shared page template, ensure it only appears in your `index.html` file - otherwise you'll end up telling the search engines that all pages should be considered duplicates of the home page!

**Note:** although this will resolve the issue for you, it may well take some time before the changes are reflected in your SEO software (or Google Webmasters).  You have to wait until the search engines next index your website and recognize the changes, which could be up-to several weeks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. I opened my index.html file and added the <link rel="canonical" href="http://your-domain.com/" /> within the <head>, and re-run the SEO, but it still showed I have duplicate title tag and meta description tag, why ?

Comment: It takes time for Google to re-crawl your site. Was it resolved?