# Google Webmaster Tools - Duplicate content (slash and none slash version of a page)

Tags: url, google-search-console, duplicate-content

Google Webmaster Tools shows a lot duplicate content in the following pages: www.example.com/example 
www.example.com/example/

I do NOT offer two versions of any page on my website, when you type example.com/example you are REDIRECTED to example.com/example/. However, Webmaster Tools shows the both versions of all my pages, considering it to be a duplicate content.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: this is sorted using a **canonical** reference in the top of the page, see example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021120/how-to-remove-a-duplicate-title-tag-and-meta-description-tag-with-canonical-link and - just add the `<meta>` tag to the `<head>`